# How to calculate how many rows and columns are needed

Tags: javascript, html-table, modulo

I want to produce a table with Javascript. I want to give it a number and that's how many cells are created. There are always to be 3 columns however (3 pictures per row)

Could someone help me out with this? I think I need to use the modulus operator but I am unsure of how to use it correctly.

I do not want any extra cells. I can calculate the rows without issue but I don't want extra cells for those rows if that makes sense. So once the cells have been made that row ends even if it's 1 or 2 cells short.

I have this at the moment:

```
rows = ?? //Not sure how to calculate this
columns = 3;
str = "";
str += '<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">';

for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   str += '<tr>';
   for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      str += '<td>' +  (i + j) + '</td>';
   }
   str += '</tr>';
}

str += '</table>';
```

Comment: You may get better help if you describe the result you want since we may have better ways to get that. For example jQuery masonry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following code that what you want.

```
var numOfPics = 100; // Number of Pictures
var columns = 3, rows = Math.ceil(numOfPics / columns), content = "", count = 1;
content = "<table border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='5'>";
for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
   content += "<tr>";
   for (c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      content += "<td>" + count + "</td>";
      if (count == numOfPics)break;  // here is check if number of cells equal Number of Pictures to stop
      count++;
   }
   content += "</tr>";
}
content += "</table>";

document.body.innerHTML = content; // insert `content` value into body of page
```

Comment: This works...sort of.. It displays 1 picture less than it is suppose to. So if numOfPics is 5 it shows 4. I can manually do + 1 to whatever the value is and it'll be fixed, but why does this occur? Will accept answer once I figure it/get told.

Comment: Check my code again in my answer. now the code start from `1` and ends to `numOfPics`. now you don't need to do `+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Say if u have number of pictures as numPictures:-
Then

```
var numRows = Math.ceil(numPictures/3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You know how many cells there are.  So you divide the number of cells by the number of columns to get the number of rows.  `Math.ceil()` rounds up in case there are not the exact amount of cells to fill a row.

`rows = Math.ceil(total_num_cells / 3);`

Comment: Something I want to add is that I don't want any extra cells hanging around. Just the ones which are wanted.

Comment: if you are talking about having a non-rectangular table then this should be done with floating divs instead.  If you want to remove excess pics that wouldn't fill an entire row, then use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.ceil`